# Importing Javascript to Angular Component Issue

Tags: javascript, angular

In a given component I have the following import:

```
import { Gantt } from '@frappe-gantt';
```

This `@frappe-gantt` is declared in `tsconfig.json`, under `paths` property, as

```
  "@frappe-gantt": [
    "frappe-gantt"
  ]
```

In a given folder, called frappe-gantt, I also have the following `index.ts`:

```
import * as Gantt from './frappe-gantt.js';

export {Gantt};
```

And the following `frappe-gantt.js` as:

```
var Gantt= (function (id,tasks,options) {
...
class Gantt {
...
constructor(param1,param2,param3){...}
...
}
return Gantt;
}());
```

However, calling `new Gantt(params,params2,params3)` in the component, using the `onInit` function, it gives me the following:

```
_frappe_gantt__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.Gantt is not a constructor
```

Does anyone have any clue on what the issue should be?

Thanks!

Comment: IIFE don't return anything, meaning your `Gantt` variable is `undefined`. Also, you have made a syntax error, meaning you didn't even write an IIFE. Consider using tools that you understand and know how to use before jumping to such code ...

Comment: Try returning a function in Grantt initialization

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, stick to basic syntax to make it work.

```js
var v1 = (function() {})(); // IIFE

console.log(v1); // undefined

var v2 = (function() {}()); // Your take on a IIFE

console.log(v2); // undefined

var v3 = function() {}; // A function that can be used with the new keyword
var i3 = new v3();

console.log(v3, i3); // displays the function and the instance of that function

class V4 {} // A JS class
var i4 = new V4();

console.log(V4, i4); // Displays the class and the instance of that class
```